# What is the time complexity of this 'first non repeating character' function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How well is this function in terms of performance and code style?

To return the first non repeating character in a string if there is one:

```py
def fnrc(string):
   dict = {d:0 for d in string}
   for d in string:
       dict[d] +=1
   try:
       return [c for c in dict if dict[c] == 1][0] 
   except IndexError:
       return 'All characters repeat'
```

Am i correct in thinking this is O(n) time as all i'm doing is looping over an iterable several times?

Comment: `O(n)` simply because you are iterating over the whole string in the first line

Comment: Prior to Python 3.7, this returns *a* non-repeating character, not necessarily the first one that occurs in the string.

Comment: Change the list comprehension to use `for c in string` to make it find the first one in the string in any version of Python.

Comment: @rdas can i get it quicker -- say O(logn)?

Comment: No, because if there are no repeating characters you'll have to test every character in the string somehow.

Comment: @Jay How will you count every character in a string without iterating over every character?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get better than O(n), but still you can heavily optimize this code. Check this:

```
def fnrc(string):
   dct = {}
   for d in string:
       dct[d] = dct.get(d, 0) + 1
   for c, v in dct.items():
       if v == 1:
           return c
   else:
       return 'All characters repeat'
```

or

```
from collections import Counter
def fnrc(string):
   for c, v in Counter(string).items():
       if v == 1:
           return c
   else:
       return 'All characters repeat'
```

against your code using `timeit` - I believe you'll see an improvement, especially for long strings.

Comment: or `from collections import Counter`

Comment: @DeepSpace I did some testing - version using `Counter` is somewhat slower on short strings, but way faster on long ones, so I added it to my answer.